# Insert a picture into a word processing document with text wrap mode "Behind The Text" using open xml 2.7.2

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I was trying to insert image for existing .docx file with text wrap mode "Behind The Text" using open xml 2.7.2 C#

example:

[image: fig 1]

And I also tried the code in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document) which is for open xml 2.5 and when try to open the output document it gives the error

> The file cannot be opened because there is a problem with the content.

So is there any updated way to do this in open xml 2.7.2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing what you want to do in Word, saving the file, and then looking at the OpenXML code that the *OpenXML Productivity Toolkit* generates (that tool is downloadable from Microsoft)?  It's essential for figuring out issues like this.

Comment: By the way, you can *diff* two Word (or Excel...) files in that tool. Often, you have something working and want to add a feature. So, you create a Word file without the feature and save it. Then add the feature and save the file with a different name. Diff the two files and you can see what changes are needed to implement the feature. Oh, and there's a *validation* feature that can help when a file you create can't be opened

Comment: Could you post a solution?